# Common children, but different root: possible to avoid re-render and re-mount in children?

Tags: reactjs, optimization, react-router

Our current app has each screen implement a `AppLayout` component, that takes a `body` and a `header` prop.

While the `body` prop is often very different, the (quite complex) `header` has a lot of repeating content between the various screens. At times just the title text is changing.

Currently, going from one route to another rerenders the entire screen, a quite wasteful operation given the similar content. Is there a way of avoid re-rendering and re-mounting of common sub-components between two screens?

**Example of routing setup**

This shows how a lot is seemingly repeated in the trees.

```
<Route
  exact
  path='/user'
  component={()=> {
      return (<AppLayout
          header={<AppHeader heading="Users"/>}
          main={<UserList/>} />);
  } />
<Route
  exact
  path='/user/new'
  component={()=>{
      return (<AppLayout
          header={<AppHeader heading="Create user"/>}
          main={<UserAccountAdd />} />);
  } />
<Route
  exact
  path='/user/:userId'
  component={({ match }) => 
      return (<AppLayout
          header={<AppHeader heading="User profile"/>}
          main={<UserAccountInfo userId={match.params.userId}/>}
          />)
  } />
```

The `AppHeader` component basically looks like

```
connected(div)
    ReallyExpensiveFoo
    ReallyExpensiveBar
    <p>{this.props.title}</p>
```

Basically I would like to have seen that the `<p>` tag of header that renders the heading title should remount.

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't update whole DOM on each state update. Instead it lets each class component to decide if it should be re-rendered by calling its [`shouldComponentUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) method. For functional components it, most likely, simply compares component props to decide if component should re-render.

You can avoid re-rendering of the component by converting your component into class component and by implementing your own version of `shouldComponentUpdate()`. However normally it is not necessary as default behavior (or versions provided by e.g. Redux's [`connect()`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) HoC) are smart enough to avoid unnecessary re-rendering and provide good application's performance.

Comment: That advice is a bit too general; basically just the usual render optimization and not applicable in this case. Also it's a bit wrong concerning functional components; they _always_ re-render, but this is usually quite cheap, so it doesn't matter all that much. It's the DOM work - unmounting and mounting, which is expensive. That's what I would like to avoid.

Comment: But I did add some of the specifics on re-mounting while you were adding your answer, so that's perhaps a bit unfair to hold against you :-)

Comment: More specific answer will require deeper knowledge of your application's state. Your example, that was added later to the question, shows that you basically want to keep large chunks of DOM nodes into browser's DOM. It can be easily achieved by adding `style={display:'none'}` or something similar to root nodes of your `ReallyExpensive...` components that should not be visible at this particular point of time. In this case they will remain in DOM, but will not be visible. However you right, your initial question was looking like request for general advice.

Answer (score 0):

React Router has a good [SideBar example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar) on their site that is quite relevant. Basically it injects pairwise `Route`s at different parts in the hierarchy, so they update independently to routing changes.